# How to find from elements with one to multiple class names just the ones which feature exactly a specific and sole class name (and not any other)?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

Example:

```html
<div class="parent father"> ... </div>
<div class="parent"> ... </div>
```

```js
const soleParentClassElementList = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')
```

With the above code line I would query both element nodes, but I want to query just the one(s) with a single `parent` class.

Comment: can you please share html structure?

Comment: @IOEnthusiast ... how would the OP usually target such element(s) by css selectors? Does the OP know about the existence of the [`:not` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)?

Comment: `var onlyParent = document.getElementsByClassName('.parent')` Try this instead of querySelector

Comment: When you are using ```doument.querySelector('.xyz')``` it selects the first element with the specified class name. In your case, it will always select the first "parent" class and not the second class and not the second div with class as "parent father".

Comment: would I have to :not every single possible class that comes after the base one that I need?

Comment: I need all the elements, so it should be querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way...

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('[class="parent"]')
  .forEach(node => node.textContent = 'this one');
```

```html
<div class="parent father"> ... </div>
<div class="parent"> ... </div>
```